# como modificar objetos de un form, desde otro form, QT creator

Tags: c++, qt

¿Cómo puedo modificar los componentes de un mainform.ui (Qlabels, comboBox, etc.) desde otro form, y viceversa? ej: 1-mainform.ui tiene un botón (llamado "button1"), cuando hago clic en button1 quiero desactivar un botón ubicado en otherform.ui (llamado "button2") 
2- cuando hago clic en el botón de otherform.ui 2 , quiero borrar un comboBox, ubicado en mainform.ui

En el ejemplo # 1: no sé cómo hacer referencia a otherform.ui, usando la form> otherform obj; obj.ui.button2.disabled (); El compilador me muestra un error !.

en el ej n. ° 2: en otherform.cpp hago referencia a mainform.ui, creando un tipo de objeto mainform, (mainform obj;), y luego obj.ui.comboBox.clear () ;, cuando ejecuto la aplicación, aparece un error > mainform * ui es privado, por lo que voy a mainform.h y  hago ui público, entonces no suceden errores, pero tampoco pasa nada.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si será esta la duda, pero con los SIGNALS/SLOTS de Qt deberías de poder resolver esa cuestión. Se trata de crear SLOTS que relacionen los widget y realicen la función que busques.
Un ejemplo (sin formularios):
**class widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
class QPushButton;
class QHBoxLayout;

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

public slots:
    void DesactivarBoton();

private:    
    QHBoxLayout* lienzo;
    QPushButton* bt1, *bt2;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**class widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    lienzo = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    bt1 = new QPushButton("Boton 1");
    bt2 = new QPushButton("Boton 2");
    lienzo->addWidget(bt1);
    lienzo->addWidget(bt2);
    connect (bt1,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(DesactivarBoton()));
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
}

void Widget::DesactivarBoton()
{
    if (bt2->isEnabled())
    {
        bt2->setEnabled(false);
    }
    else
    {
        bt2->setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Si los widgets están creados en formularios, tendrás que crear el slot (y tal vez la señal) en la clase que los define y hacer la conexion SIGNAL/SLOT en el widget que los aloja.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es capturar la señal `clicked()` de `button1`. Esto lo puedes hacer directamente desde el entorno gráfico o mediante un código similar a este:

```
class MainForm
{
private slots:
  void button1_clicked();
};

MinForm::MainForm()
{
  // ...
  connect(button1,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(button1_clicked()));
}

void MainForm::button1_clicked()
{
}
```

Con este código ya has conseguido que cada vez que se haga *click* en `button1` se llame a la función `button1_click`.

A partir de este punto, la resolución del problema se puede hacer de diferentes maneras:

**1. De forma tradicional**

En este caso necesitas que `MainForm` tenga, de alguna manera, un puntero a `OtherForm`:

```
class MainForm
{
private:
  OtherForm* otherForm;
};
```

Una vez conseguido eso, la forma de deshabilitar el botón dependerá de si el objeto `button2` es público o privado. Si es público se puede hacer la desactivación directamente y, si no, habrá que preparar una función que nos permita modificar el estado de activación del botón:

```
void MainForm::button1_clicked()
{
  // Si button2 es public
  otherForm->button2->setEnabled(false);

  // Si es private
  otherForm->setButton2Enabled(false);
}
```

**2. Con señales y slots**

Otra forma de resolver el problema pasa por no capturar la señal en el formulario principal sino directamente sobre aquel que vamos a actuar.

Una forma sencilla sería aprovechar el momento en el que se crea `otherForm` para enlazar la señal `clicked` de `button1` con este *slot*:

```
class OtherForm
{
public slots:
  void CambiarEstadoBoton()
  {
    button2->setEnabled(!button2->isEnabled());
  }
};

void MainForm::CrearOtherForm()
{
  OtherForm* otherForm = new OtherForm;
  connect(button1,SIGNAL(clicked()),
          otherForm,SLOT(CambiarEstadoBoton()));
}
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que `QPushButton` no dispone de un *slot* que permute el estado de activación. Tenemos [`setEnabled`,](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop) pero para que funcione tenemos que decirle si queremos activar o desactivar el botón... no nos sirve salvo que deseemos que `button2` el botón de `MainForm` se vaya a quedar pulsado. Si este fuese el caso podríamos ahorrarnos la función `CambiarEstadoBoton` y enlazar la señal de `button1` con el *slot*  de `button2`:

```
void MainForm::CrearOtherForm()
{
  OtherForm* otherForm = new OtherForm;
  connect(button1,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),
          otherForm,SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));
}
```